# Getting all combination of 2 elements from a string array java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, hash, hashmap

Lets say I have this array list ['a', 'b', 'xx'].
I want to extract every 2 strings combination (for every 2 elements). for example ['a','b'] ['a', 'xx']  ['b', 'a'] ['b', 'xx']  ['xx', 'a'] ['xx', 'b'].

I have written this code, but when the array gets really big (10k for 
example) the GC runs out of memory.

```
        private Text empty = new Text("");

    public void start(Iterable<Text> values,Context context) throws {
        List<String> sitesArr = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<String, String> hmapPairs = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (Text site : values){
            sitesArr.add(site.toString());
        }

        insertPairsToHash(hmapPairs, sitesArr);
        writeContextFromHash(hmapPairs, context);
    } 

    private void insertPairsToHash(HashMap<String, String> hmapPairs, List<String> sitesArr) {
        for (int i=0; i<sitesArr.size(); i++) {
            for (int j=i+1; j<sitesArr.size(); j++) {
                String firstPair = sitesArr.get(i) + "_" + sitesArr.get(j);
                String secondPair = sitesArr.get(j) + "_" + sitesArr.get(i);
                hmapPairs.put(firstPair,secondPair);
            }      
        }
    }

    private void writeContextFromHash(HashMap<String, String> hmapPairs, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Text textTowriteToFile = new Text("");
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hmapPairs.entrySet()) {
            textTowriteToFile.set(entry.getKey());
            context.write(textTowriteToFile, empty);
            textTowriteToFile.set(entry.getValue());
            context.write(textTowriteToFile, empty);
        }
    }
```

I use 2 for loops and in each iteration I insert 2 combinations ( ['a', 'b'] and ['b','a'] first element is the key and the second is the value so in ['a','b'] 'a' would be the key and 'b' would be the value and vice versa) to the hash.
Then I iterate once over the hash to send the values.
How can I make it faster while using less memory?

Comment: I don't think that `insertPairsToHash()` does what you want to do : computing all possible ordered dependent combinations.

Comment: Just for 2 pairs

Comment: And you have memory problem with that ? You should give more information such as the stracktrace when the memory error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call "writeContextFromHash" right in the nested for loop and not create HashMap?

Comment: You are absolutely right ! HashMap takes too much memory. So that's solves the memory issue. can you think of a faster way to get all the desired values ?

Comment: Another thing you can do is not to create "sitesArr" at all and iterate over "values" in the nested loop. This is different than your loop logic but given original expected outcome you can achieve it with n*n iterations which might be a little too long but can save you a memory by not having to store 10k elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add some more information to your question. But basically with this kind of programme you will always run into memory problems as your input gets larger. With 10k entries you end up at about 100m combinations resulting in 50m Map entries. Multiplied with the size of the data structure (depending on your input) this uses a lot of memory.
If you know the rough size of your input beforehand you might just assign enough memory to your jvm (unless your machine is to small). If this doesn't solve the problem you cannot keep all results in memory. Either swap out to disk or as suggested above write your results directly to the console instead of keeping them in memory.

Comment: thanks, writing to console as suggested in other responses

Answer (score 0):

You can simply refactor your class streaming results. So you do not keep the whole list of result of your combining elements.

```
    private Text empty = new Text("");

   public void start(Iterable<Text> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException  {
       List<String> sitesArr = new ArrayList<String>();

       for (Text site : values){
           sitesArr.add(site.toString());
       }
       insertPairsToHash(sitesArr,context);
   } 

   private void insertPairsToHash(List<String> sitesArr, Context context) {
       for (int i=0; i<sitesArr.size(); i++) {
           for (int j=i+1; j<sitesArr.size(); j++) {
               String firstPair = sitesArr.get(i) + "_" + sitesArr.get(j);
               String secondPair = sitesArr.get(j) + "_" + sitesArr.get(i);

               doWrite(context, firstPair, secondPair);
           }      
       }
   }

    private void doWrite(Context context, String firstPair, String secondPair) {
        Text textTowriteToFile = new Text("");
           textTowriteToFile.set(firstPair);
           context.write(textTowriteToFile, empty);
           textTowriteToFile.set(secondPair);
           context.write(textTowriteToFile, empty);
    }
```

This will lower you memory usage.

In general you try to stream results if your input is big or unbounded, streaming add some complexity but keeps the memory usage independent from the size of you input.

### EDIT (After comment):

You can drop used elements by removing them from the list.
You should in this case use a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList, because removing the head element from an array list would involve much more GC and CPU time then the same operation from a linked list.

This however will not lower the peak memory usage, only the usage over time (you will require less memory as the process goes on).

It could still be useful if other components consume more memory as the process progresses.

```
 List<String> sitesArr = new LinkedList<>();

private void insertPairsToHash(List<String> sitesArr, Context context) {
    while (!sitesArr.isEmpty()) {
        String left = sitesArr.remove(0);
        for (String right : sitesArr) {
            String firstPair = left + "_" + right;
            String secondPair = right + "_" + left;
            doWrite(context, firstPair, secondPair);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, after tsolakp response I did just that, can you think of a better way to extract the combinations tho ? thank